# An AddColumn was added to migration even though table is unchanged

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-3.1

I have the following model in a EF Core 3 project:

```
public class MemberModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(30)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(255)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required, Display(Name="Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

The `CompanyId` property was added only in March, and a migration, with timestamp 20200226063529 was done:

```
public partial class addedCompanyIdColumn : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "CompanyId",
            table: "Members",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "CompanyId",
            table: "Members");
    }
}
```

In the interim, I modified the table to add [Required] attribute to the fields, and I didn't apply any migrations.

Today, I added a migration to do update some other table, and the migration code included code that alters the `Members` table, adding a `CompanyId` column, and creating a `Companies` table that was already there:

```
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Phone",
            table: "Members",
            maxLength: 30,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(30)",
            oldMaxLength: 30,
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Name",
            table: "Members",
            maxLength: 255,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(255)",
            oldMaxLength: 255,
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Email",
            table: "Members",
            maxLength: 255,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(255)",
            oldMaxLength: 255,
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "CompanyId",
            table: "Members",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0);

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Companies",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 255, nullable: true),
                isDeleted = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Companies", x => x.Id);
            });
```

So the update failed. I had to go to the database to delete the `CompanyId` column and the `Companies` table in order to proceed.

What could have caused this issue, and what should I look out for to avoid such outcomes in future?

Is there a requirement that any changes to the models, no matter how trivial, should be followed by a database update before any transactions are performed?

Comment: is it possible that some other person had access to the DB and manually updated it?

Comment: There are several people working on this project checked into TFS. Each of our own databases has the `CompanyId` column, shouldn't this indicate that there was a prior successful migration that added the column?